# Reading zipped vs unzipped files into memory

Tags: java, memory

I have a single file, delivered as .zip, and i want to read it into memory. Zipped it is about 50 MB and unzipped about 700MB. Now i am wondering if i should unzip the file first and then read it or if it makes no difference and i can read the data from the zip file directly.

In case of a normal file i use a `InputStreamReader` wrapped around a `FileInputStream`. 
For a zip file i use a `java.util.ZipFile` to get the `InputStream` from a `ZipEntry` and then again wrap a `InputStreamReader` around it.
So in the end i work with `InputStreamReader` in both cases.

I tried to test it, but locally i can't read such a large file without running out of memory. On the server where the process runs are more processes interfering so i couldn't quite tell if there is any difference.

Does anybody know, if one of the options uses significantly more memory than the other ot is it just a question of design, which way to use?

Greetings,
Uwe

Comment: what do you do with the unzipped data? how many entries has the zipfile?

Comment: Is this a one-off job on your own machine, rather than a regular job on a production one?

Comment: We really need to know what you have to do with the data. You could filter it on read, only needing to hold a small buffer plus your results in memory - or you could just find a way to process it on disk. Holding it all in memory should always be avoided - unless this is a one-off.

Comment: @wero A csv file is contained. After reading i group the single rows by the content of one column and write the result back to the disk. One file can contain up to 600 000 lines.

Comment: @AndrewRegan It is a regular production job. I know the memory part is a critical one but memory read needs to stay for now because we can't use Java 8 right now. Also we have no way of using batch processing because the single steps are done by single soap microservices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference is a small performance hit for unzipping the file. In both cases your `InputStreamReader` will read the unpacked 700 MB file.

The next question you should ask, is why do you need to read this large file completely into memory? Is it really necessary? Maybe you can process it line by line without holding all lines in memory.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Good to hear that my expectations were going in the right direction. I would love to use streams and lambas for this case but as our architecture goes this isn't possible right now. See my comment on my  question.

Comment: To reduce the memory consumption you can process the file in two passes. In pass 1 you store only the value of the group column in a map like `Map<String, List<Long>>`. The values are the file positions for each line containing the key in the group column. So with this you create a poor man's index. In the second pass you iterate over the map and can read all lines for one group value together. You need a `RandomAccessFile` for this to position the file pointer to the beginning of the line.